# SSH key does not save permanently

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Everytime my laptop connect to company's wifi, and committing/fetching something, git always pops error permission denied so I have to add the ssh key. The problem is that it doesn't effect permanently, I have to do it again everyday with the following commands:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-add ssh_key
```

After this, everything works fine. Is there anyway to do it once and for all?

Comment: `ssh-add` means you are using `ssh-agent`. By design, it is not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to rename your `ssh_key` file or specify it in your ssh config.

I believe the default identity files are
`id_rsa`,
`id_dsa`,
`id_ecdsa`,
`id_ed25519`.

Rename your file to one of these and ensure it is in `~/.ssh` and I think that will solve the issue.

Alternatively add/edit your `~/.ssh/config` file with an appropriate line to use this key.  Possibly something like

```
 Host *
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ssh_key
```

Comment: You should also verify the permission are correct, only the user of the key, can have access to the key.